# About the using vertices as index in graphs c++ why we wasting space

Tags: c++

I have a question about the vertices of graphs in c++. Like, let's suppose I want to have a graph with vertices as 100,200,300,400 and they are connected in some manner not important but if we are creating an adjacency list graph what we do is.

```
adj[u].push_back(v);
adj[v].push_back(u);
```

and let 400 is connected with 200 we are doing `adj[400]` and creating a large matrix of vectors when all we need was a matrix of size 4 as there are four vertices and here we going till 400 can someone explain this. Is it like in graphs we have all vertices consecutive and must start from some small number? The code works fine when you have vertices like 1,2,3,4,5. We are using vertices as an index and depending on our vertices they can vary by a lot than what we needed.

Comment: You may want [`std::map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map).

Comment: See: Sparse arrays.

Comment: @MikeCAT how about applying a modulo?

Comment: @AntoninGAVREL Modulo by what for this example `100,200,300,400`? How about when `564` is added to this?

Comment: Each vector within `adj` has a dynamic size so you aren't necessarily wasting any space. A Matrix could be more efficient if the graph is highly connected because it can be a matrix of bools whereas this solution requires storing an integer type. An adjacency list can be more efficient if the graph is sparsely connected.

Comment: @DeanJohnson but anyway you have to create a matrix of vector right which isn't dynamic and the size of the matrix depends on our vertices

Comment: You shouldn't have a matrix of vectors for an adjacency list - you should have a vector of vectors. The outer vector size is equal to the number of vertices but the size of the inner vectors is dependent on how connected the graph is. The outer vector is fixed, the inner vector is dynamic.

Comment: @DeanJohnson maybe u here is not the value of vertice it's more like the u'th vertice?

Comment: your question lacks some important details. If `adj` is a `std::map` as someone suggested then no space is wasted at all.

Comment: That doesn't change anything. An adjacency list has an outer container with fixed size == # of vertices. The inner container is dynamically sized (total size of all inner containers is `2 * (# of graph edges)`). Perhaps you are talking about a different data structure?

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 while I agree the question is lacking information, no space should be wasted if it is a vector either.

Comment: @DeanJohnos whatever, the only reason space is wasted is assumptions made by OP without stating them clearly ;)

Comment: @DeanJohnson when you access adj[400] that means 401st element right? and I have only 4elements. I guess I have to look more into it.

Comment: @CodingKrlo I think I understand your problem better - the index into the outer container does not need to be the value of the graph. I've posted an answer describing this.

Comment: @DeanJohnson yeah thanks now I got it the indexes arent necessarily the values of the vertiices. Thank for the help

Comment: Why not just creating a list of links, you would save bytes and also performance. such as `struct link { std::size_t vtx1; std::size_t vtx2; };`, and then have `std::vector<link> list;` that can be filled: `list.emplace_back(u,v);`. So after that, you just need to run over the 1D vector and get the connection between the two. If you implement `bool operator<(const link& l, const link& r);` in the struct, you would even be able to sort the `std::vector`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An adjacency list stores a list of the connected vertices for each vertex in the graph. For example, given this graph:

```
1---2
|\  |
| \ |
|  \|
3---4
```

You would store:

```
1: 2, 3, 4
2: 1, 4
3: 1, 4
4: 1, 2, 3
```

This can be done with a `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`. Note that you do not need to use the values of the graph as the indexes into these vectors. If the values of the graph were instead `100, 200, 300, 400` you could use a separate map container to convert from vertex value to an index into the adjacency list (`std::unordered_map<ValueType, IndexType>`). You could also store a Vertex structure such as this:

```
struct Vertex {
int index; // 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, etc.
int value; // 100, 200, or whatever value you want
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the problem is exactly but i guess si about the speed, the most simple and easy fix is to have a "memory layout" like in a pixel buffer, a index is a implicit value defied by de position since each segment is.

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------...
| float, float, float, float | float, float, float, float | float, 
-------------------------------------------------------------------...
| index 0                    | index 1                    | index 2
-------------------------------------------------------------------...
```

As you didn't give a sample code to give a better idea the example asumes a lot if things but basically implements the layout idea; using arrays is not needed, is my preference, vector would give almost no performance penalty the bigges one being the resizement; some of the lines are not intuitive, like why is a operation + a array faster than having an array inside an array, it just is, the memory is slower than te cpu.

Small note, bacause all the "small arrays" are just a big array you need to worrie of overflows and underflow or add a check; if some vertex groups are smaller that the chunk size just waste the space, the time to compact and un compact the data is worst in most cases than having the padding.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

template <typename VAL>
struct Ver_Map {

    VAL * base_ptr;
    uint32_t map_size;
    uint32_t vertex_len;

    void alloc_map(uint32_t elem, uint32_t ver_len, VAL in){
        base_ptr = new VAL[elem * ver_len] { in };
        vertex_len = ver_len;
        map_size = elem;
    }
    void free_map(){
        delete base_ptr;
    }

    VAL * operator()(uint32_t object){
        return &base_ptr[(object * vertex_len)];
    }
    VAL & operator()(uint32_t object, uint32_t vertex){
        return base_ptr[(object * vertex_len) + vertex];
    }

};

int main (void) {

    const uint32_t map_len = 10000;

    Ver_Map<float> ver_map;
    ver_map.alloc_map(map_len, 4, 0.0f);

    // Use case

    ver_map(0, 2) = 0.5f;
    std::cout << ver_map(0)[1] << std::endl;
    std::cout << ver_map(0)[2] << std::endl;
    std::cout << ver_map(0, 2) << std::endl;

    // Size in memory

    std::cout << "Size of struct -> " 
    << (map_len * sizeof(float)) + sizeof(Ver_Map<float>)
    << " bytes" << std::endl;

    // Time to fully clear

    auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

    for(int x=0; x < map_len; x++){
        for(int y=0; y < ver_map.vertex_len; y++){
            ver_map(x, y) = 1.0f;
        }
    }

    std::cout << "Full write time -> " 
    << (uint32_t)std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>
    (std::chrono::steady_clock::now() - start).count()
    << " microseconds" << std::endl;

    ver_map.free_map();

    return 0;
}
```